# How can I automatically forward all paramters from one method to another in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods, super, method-call

If I have methods:

```
def method_a(p1, p2)
  # do some stuff
  method_b(p1, p2)
end

def method_b(p1, p2)
  # do other stuff
end
```

Is there a way to call `method_b` and automatically pass all parameters to it? (Sort like how you can call `super` and it automatically forwards all params)

Comment: Personally; yuck. I'm not comfortable with the `super` magic, either, actually. This is one of those cases where IMO being explicit should be the default choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know one appriximate method:

```
def method_a *args
   # do some stuff
   method_b *args
end

def method_b *args
   # do other stuff
end
```

or expanding arguments in the second method:

```
def method_a *args
   # do some stuff
   method_b *args
end

def method_b p1, p2
   # do other stuff
end
```

Since `super` is key-work method, the ruby interperter can treat it as of the same argument list as in the specific method you've called. But default from to call a method without argument is the same as for `super` method, just method name:

```
method_a # calls to :method_a without arguments, not as the same argument list for the caller method.
```

So, it will be strong omonim for the call method syntax.

Comment: This is definitely a plausible way to go. Both methods will always have the same parameters (in my current case). I was hoping to name them explicitly for readability as I do now, but if this is the only option, might have to go for it.

Comment: I added a short description why call to `super` isn't the same as call to other named method.

Answer (score 1):

Considering arbitrary number of arguments and a possibility of a block, the most general format is:

```
def method_a(*args, &pr)
  # do some stuff
  method_b(*args, &pr)
end
```

Then, in the definition of `method_b`, you can set a specific number of arguments and whether or not it takes a block.

Comment: This will not catch keyword parameters, unfortunately.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: It will catch keyword parameters, these will appear as a hash at the end of `args`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `*args` like this:

```
def method_a(*args)
  ...
  method_b(*args)
end

def method_b(p1, p2)
  ...
end
```

You can process the arguments like an array in the method_a.

Comment: You forgot to use the splat operator when invoking method_b.

Answer (score -1):

Wow, this is hacky. But it works

```
def fwd_call b, meth
  send(meth, *b.eval('method(__method__).parameters.map { |p| eval(p.last.to_s) }'))
end

def method1 x, y
  fwd_call(binding, :method2)
end

def method2 x, y
  x+y
end

puts method1(3, 4)
# 7
```